# Why does my bot break after I add @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

The bot works perfectly fine but when I add

`@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)`

Then the code breaks and I get this error:

***File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\abc.py", line 427, in permissions_for
roles = member.roles
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'roles'***

But the problem is that the error is not in the file where the code for the bot is. The error is in some random site-packages folder.

Entire command code:

```
@client.command(aliases=["Server"])
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True) 
async def ServerInfo(ctx):
  guild = ctx.guild
  embed = discord.Embed(title="Server Info", colour = 0xFF0000, timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow())
  embed.add_field(name = "Server name:", value = f"{guild.name}", inline = False)
  embed.add_field(name = "Members:", value = f"{len(guild.members)}", inline = False)
  embed.add_field(name = "Boosters", value = f"{guild.premium_subscribers}", inline = False)
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
  print("ServerInfo works")
```

Comment: Are you sure none of the lines in the error refer to your code?

Comment: Yes because the code is only 70 lines long

Comment: Try removing the @commands.has_permissions decorator, and then do `print(type(ctx), type(ctx.author), type(ctx.message.author))`

Comment: This is what I get when I run the command:
<class 'discord.ext.commands.context.Context'> <class 'discord.user.User'> <class 'discord.user.User'>

Answer (score 1):

That is very, very odd. I'll try to explain why it might be happening, but I need more info than just one line of code. If you could update your post with the entire command that would be helpful.

The error results from trying to get `.roles` from a `discord.User` object. Only the `discord.Member` object has the `.roles` attribute. The decorator you added will check `ctx.author.roles`, where `ctx.author` *should* be a `discord.Member`. Apparently, it isn't.

Here are a couple possible reasons that I can think of:

- You invoked the command with a `commands.Context` that you created yourself, and you gave it a user instead of member.
- You didn't add the decorator to a command. This might occur if you put this decorator on an event such as `reaction_add`, and the message author has left the server.

A good starting point would be to remove the decorator, and then print the type of `ctx`, `ctx.message.author`, and `ctx.author`.

Comment: I haven't added commands.Context anywhere in the code so I do not think that should be the problem. For the second reason, I do not know what a decorator command is. I have edited the post to the full code for the command.

Comment: The easiest explanation is that the command was invoked in DMs

Comment: Well the command was used in the test server and not in dms.